# Tomcat SQL doesn't refresh

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat7

I have a Java RESTful Webservice running on Tomcat7 in Ubuntu.
When I change fields in the Database the Webservice returns the old values.
When i restart the service, it returns the new values.

this is my Context.xml:

```
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/schischule"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/Skischul_DB"
username="admin"
password="pwd"
maxActive="20"
maxIdle="30"
maxWait="-1"
/>
</Context>
```

Has anyone an idea why Tomcat doesn't refresh the data?
THX

Comment: How you access data from your web service, do you use any ORM layer  with any caching frameworks ?

Comment: No if i restart the Server , then it gets the New values. So it must be a Problem with the Server...